# FBSDKGraphRequest to sign up Parse users is "ambiguous?"

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, swift2

The FBSDKGraphRequest connection handler used in the SignUpViewController of a tutorial app is now outdated. I updated it to a point where it won't error until I try to place the Parse code after the user successfully signs up. Once I put in the Parse code (to sign the user up using the FB SDK results), I get the errors "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

Here's what I have so far:

```
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender, email"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler ({ connection, result, error in
        if error != nil {
            //onError()
            print(error)
            return
        } else {
                 let fbResult = result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                 print("FbResult \(fbResult)")

                 PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"]
                 PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]

                 try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()

                 let userId = result["id"] as! String
                                  let facebookProfilePictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large"

            if let fbpicUrl = NSURL(string: facebookProfilePictureUrl) {

                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fbpicUrl) {

                    self.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: data)!

                    PFUser.currentUser()?["image"] = imageFile

                    try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
                }
    })
```

For some reason XCode hates anything after the "print fbresult" line. Here's a pastebin of the working code before the Parse code:

http://pastebin.com/dUyEvYmr

How can I update this to accept the Parse code?

Thanks!!

PS: I can confirm that I have the latest Parse and FB SDK. I'm running the latest version of XCode (7.2.1).

Comment: This is probably due to missing type annotation for fbResult. It doesn't know how to handle 'AnyObject', and that is causing the error. This has nothing to do with the SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I came across with the same problem when going through the udemy swift class too.

My solution was:

```
if let fbResult = {
    ...
    let name : NSString = (fbResult.valueForKey("name") as? NSString)!
    let gender : NSString = (fbResult.valueForKey("gender") as? NSString)! 
    ...
}
```

Hope it works for you!